# Expect Not Handling request in Auto-SSH

Tags: ssh, expect

I am trying to automate the process of SSH by using the following command,

```
sudo ssh -o ConnectTimeout=2400 $hostname /root && 
  sudo expect -c "spawn /usr/bin/ssh $1 id;expect -brace {\"hostname's password: \" {send \"password\r\";expect -brace {eof {exit}}};eof {exit}}"
```

When I run the script, it still asks me for the password. I do not know why this is happening , since I have already taken care of that with expect and send.

Anything wrong??

UPDATE:

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=2400 root@$1 -o expect -c "spawn /usr/bin/ssh root@hostname id;expect -brace {\"root@hostname's password: \" {send \"password\r\";expect -brace {eof {exit}}};eof {exit}}"
```

I have edited the script. It still prompts me for a password when I run this. My diagnosis is that the Expect is not working.

Ashwin

Comment: I don't grok your code: as root, you're connecting to $hostname to execute the program "/root", then, if that returned successfully, as root you're calling expect (from your local machine, not from $hostname) to connect to $1. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: the $1 is a parameter passed into the code, which is the hostname. Apologies for that , I forgot to edit it.

Comment: Why are there 2 `ssh` commands there? Please explain what you want to do

Comment: That was a mistake ..... I have edited the script to,

Comment: ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=2400 root@$1 -o expect -c "spawn /usr/bin/ssh root@hostname id;expect -brace {\"root@hostname's password: \" {send \"password\r\";expect -brace {eof {exit}}};eof {exit}}"

Comment: Working fine on Linux, not working on Mac.

Comment: Edit the question to fix the problems. Don't just add comments. Also, what does "not working" mean? Are there errors?

Comment: Sorry ! I am new to this.

Comment: Just remember that you are asking strangers to help you for free. Make it as easy as possible for us to help you.

Comment: Can Somebody please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You have

> ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=2400 root@$1 -o expect -c "spawn /usr/bin/ssh root@hostname id;expect -brace {\"root@hostname's password: \" {send \"password\r\";expect -brace {eof {exit}}};eof {exit}}"

You are needlessly complicating the expects. There's also an extra `-o` option for `ssh` that is probably the biggest error.

Rewritten, your command can be

```
ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o ConnectTimeout=2400 root@$1 expect -c '
    spawn /usr/bin/ssh root@hostname id
    expect {
        "root@hostname's password: " {
            send \"password\r\"
            exp_continue
        }
        eof {exit}
    }
'
```

Using outer single quotes removes the need to escape the inner double quotes.